# Does following code wait for forEach to finish

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, foreach, promise

I have a large array containing various data, and a function that performs some basic but somewhat time-consuming analysis on the array.

I use a forEach loop to iterate over the array. I want the function to return a specific element if a condition is met, otherwise false, using Promises since the function could take a considerable amount of time to complete:

```
var analyzeData = function (arr) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var answer = false;

        arr.forEach(function (elm) {
            if (elm.foo == true) {
                answer = elm;
            }
        });

        resolve(answer);
    });
}
```

The issue I'm encountering is that I suspect that `answer` is being resolved before the forEach loop completes; i.e. before the forEach loop can finish checking every element's `foo` property, the function resolves to `answer`, which is by default false.

Is there a way to ensure that the code following the forEach loop waits for the loop to finish iterating, or loop through the array in some other manner?

Comment: `Array.prototype.forEach()` is synchronous. So it finishes its iteration over all array elements and only then interpreter evaluates the next statement.

Comment: @zerkms I thought so as well - any ideas why I would be encountering this issue then?

Comment: @apparatix: We don't know what issue you're encountering. You should [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @apparatix: I'm not sure what "issue" you're referring to. This code resolves the promise **after** iteration is completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript loop iteration is synchronous, and in your code you will always complete the loop before the call to `resolve` is made.

Note that JavaScript is also single threaded, so putting this in a promise won't make it run in the background. There will still be some period of time in which the UI not responsive to the user while this loop is executing.

You can offload some computation to background processes using [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers).

As an aside: can you exit the loop when the first item is found? If not, why not iterate in reverse (using a for-loop, not array reversal) and exit when the first item is found? It is still technically O(N) in the worst case, but the best case is O(1) if you bail out as soon as possible.

However to be more helpful, you will need to provide more information about what is happening. I would suggest putting together a small example on http://jsfiddle.net/ -- that can be a useful exercise in and of itself.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Drew! The issue actually lay in an API call I was making previously :/ Also, I use Promises not for asynchronous/background computation, but because the return value may not be available immediately - if I just use `return` the function sometimes evaluated to undefined

Comment: @apparatix, glad it helped. In the case you show there's no need for a promise unless you don't want to _start_ the computation until later.